# Update an entity that has a datatransformer on a collection field on Symfony

Tags: symfony, collections, entity, transformer-model

My project is on Symfony 2.6.

I have an Entity `Request` with a collection of `User` `contributers`.

I have a form in order to add a `contributer` to a `request`. This form contains a data transformer in order to add the user by its `email`.

Everything is working just fine When I want to :

- CREATE a new `request` with an `email` corresponding to :

  - An existing `user`.
  - A NOT existing `user` : an error message appears to inform user that this `email` doesn't match any existing `user`.
- UPDATE an existing `request` by

  - UPDATING an already existing `contributer` with an `email` corresponding to

    - An existing `user`.
    - A NOT existing `user` : an error message appears to inform user that this `email` doesn't match any existing `user`.
  - ADDING a new `contributer` with an `email` corresponding to

    - An existing `user`.

BUT when I want to update an existing `request` by adding a new `contributer` with an `email` corresponding to a NOT existing `user`then it crashes :  `Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Entity\Request::addContributer() must be an instance of AppBundle\Entity\User, null given, called in C:\Users\Utilisateur\Workspace\repositories\tvjp\web-app-ws\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor.php on line 512 and defined`

Here is a workaround to handle this problem : In my `Request` entity, I modify my `addContributer` method in order to accep null `User` :

This code doesn't work :

```
public function addContributer(User $contributer){
    $this->contributers[] = $contributer;
    return $this;
}
```

This code works :

```
public function addContributer(User $contributer = null){
    if($contributer != null){
        $this->contributers[] = $contributer;
    }
    return $this;
}
```

But I think this a really dirty workaround. Any ideas of what am I missing here ?

For information, here are parts of my code.

the datatransformer

```
class UserByEmailTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface{

private $entityManager;

public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager){
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
}

public function reverseTransform($email) {
    if (!$email) { return new User(); }
    $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository('AppBundle:user')->findOneBy(array('email' => $email));
    if ($user === null) {
        throw new TransformationFailedException('Il n\'existe aucun utilisateur '.$email.'.');
    }
    return $user;
}

public function transform($user) {
    if ($user === null) { return ''; }
    return $user->getEmail();

}

}
```

The user selector

```
class UserSelectorType extends AbstractType{

private $entityManager;

public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager){
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
    $transformer = new UserByEmailTransformer($this->entityManager);
    $builder->addModelTransformer($transformer);

}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver){
    $defaults = array();
    $resolver->setDefaults($defaults);
}

public function getParent(){
    return 'email';
}

public function getName(){
    return 'userSelector';
}
}
```

The service

```
user_selector_form_type:
    class: AppBundle\Form\Selector\UserSelectorType
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: userSelector }
```

The form

```
class RequestType extends AbstractType{

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
    $isAddForm = $options['isAddForm'];
    $builder->add('contributers','collection',array(
            'label'                 => 'request.form.contributers', 
            'type'                  => 'userSelector',
            'allow_add'             => true,
            'allow_delete'          => true,
            'by_reference'          => false,
            'required'              => false,
            'options'               => array('label' => false,'invalid_message' => 'request.contributer.404',)));

    if ($isAddForm){
        $builder->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'request.form.add.submit'));
    }else{
        $builder->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'request.form.edit.submit'));
    }
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver){
    $defaults = array(
        'data_class'            => 'AppBundle\Entity\Request',
        'intention'             => 'request',
        'translation_domain'    => 'request',
        'isAddForm'             => ''
    );
    $resolver->setDefaults($defaults);
}

public function getName(){
    return 'request';
}
}
```

Comment: A few month later, have you find any "cleaner" solution ?